# Simplified Bresenham's line algorithm: What does it *exactly* do?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, bresenham

Based on Wikipedia's article on Bresenham's line algorithm I've implemented the [simplified version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Simplification) described there, my Java implementation looks like this:

```
int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);

int sx = (x1 < x2) ? 1 : -1;
int sy = (y1 < y2) ? 1 : -1;

int err = dx - dy;

while (true) {
    framebuffer.setPixel(x1, y1, Vec3.one);

    if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) {
        break;
    }

    int e2 = 2 * err;

    if (e2 > -dy) {
        err = err - dy;
        x1 = x1 + sx;
    }

    if (e2 < dx) {
        err = err + dx;
        y1 = y1 + sy;
    }
}
```

Now I do understand that `err` controls the ratio between steps on the x-axis compared to steps on the y-axis - but now that I'm supposed to document what the code is doing I fail to clearly express, what it is for, and why *exactly* the if-statements are, how they are, and why `err` is changed in the way as seen in the code.

Wikipedia doesn't point to any more detailled explanations or sources, so I'm wondering:

**What precisely does `err` do and why are `dx` and `dy` used in exactly the shown way to maintain the correct ratio between horizontal and vertical steps using this simplified version of Bresenham's line algorithm?**

Comment: Your formula over simplified. After the "if (e2 > -dy) {" block you should have another check to see if it's at the end, if so, plot then break the loop. There's cases where you'll miss one point along the x axis.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are various forms of equations for a line, one of the most familiar being `y=m*x+b`.  Now if `m=dy/dx` and `c = dx*b`, then `dx*y = dy*x + c`.  Writing `f(x) = dy*x - dx*y + c`, we have `f(x,y) = 0` iff `(x,y)` is a point on given line.

If you advance `x` one unit, `f(x,y)` changes by `dy`; if you advance `y` one unit, `f(x,y)` changes by `dx`.
In your code, `err` represents the current value of the linear functional `f(x,y)`, and the statement sequences

```
    err = err - dy;
    x1 = x1 + sx;
```

and

```
    err = err + dx;
    y1 = y1 + sy;
```

represent advancing `x` or `y` one unit (in `sx` or `sy` direction), with consequent effect on the function value.  As noted before, `f(x,y)` is zero for points on the line; it is positive for points on one side of the line, and negative for those on the other.  The `if` tests determine whether advancing `x` will stay closer to the desired line than advancing `y`, or vice versa, or both.

The initialization `err = dx - dy;` is designed to minimize offset error; if you blow up your plotting scale, you'll see that your computed line may not be centered on the desired line with different initializations.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add one bit of "why" information to jwpat's excellent answer.

The point of using the `f(x) = dy*x - dx*y + c` formulation is to speed up the calculation. This formulation uses integer arithmetic (faster), whereas the traditional `y = mx + b` formulation uses floating point arithmetic (slower).